# how to get objects's metadata name in kubernetes

Tags: rest, api, kubernetes

I can get all the things of a list of objects, such as `Secrets` and `ConfigMaps`.

```
{
"kind": "SecretList",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/secrets",
    "resourceVersion": "499638"
},
"items": [{
    "metadata": {
        "name": "aaa",
        "namespace": "kube-system",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/secrets/aaa",
        "uid": "96b0fbee-f14c-423d-9734-53fed20ae9f9",
        "resourceVersion": "1354",
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-24T11:20:23Z"
    },
    "data": "aaa"
}]
}
```

but I only want the name list, for this example :`"aaa"`. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve it by using `jsonpath` output. Note that the specification you posted will look quite differently once applied. It will create one `Secret` object in your `kube-system` namespace and when you run:

```
$ kubectl get secret -n kube-system aaa -o json
```

the output will look similar to the following:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-25T11:08:21Z",
        "name": "aaa",
        "namespace": "kube-system",
        "resourceVersion": "34488887",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/secrets/aaa",
        "uid": "229edeb3-57bf-11ea-b366-42010a9c0093"
    },
    "type": "Opaque"
}
```

To get only the `name` of your `Secret` you need to run:

```
kubectl get secret aaa -n kube-system -o jsonpath='{.metadata.name}'
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work.

```
kubectl get secretlist -o=jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.name]}" | grep -v HEAD | head -n1
```

check link in the below for more info.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/